# Linebreak of a yaml not displaying at an html file

Tags: python, html, line-breaks

I am having a ymal file and a html file where some of the content in the ymal file is loaded into the html file (see below). I would like to add linebreaks to the string in the ymal file such that it is shown in separate lines when the html file is loaded.  I am using flask and jupyter to load the html file.

The html file is loaded correctly but whatever i try it seems that I cannot get the string to break where I want it to.

Does anyone can help me to add linebreaks in the yaml files such that they are shown in the html file?

Thank you.

python code:

```
import oyaml as yaml
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['JSON_SORT_KEYS'] = False

@app.route('/')
def index():
    website_data = yaml.load(open('_config.yaml'))

    return render_template('home.html', data=website_data)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

My yaml code:

```
 profile:
  first_name: |
    I would like to have a break here.\n

    And then I would also to have a break here\\
    But it does not work whatever I try</br>.
```

My html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <h1>My homepage</h1>
    <p>{{ data.profile.first_name }} </p>
    <p>This is a test website again</p>
  </body>
</html>
```